# How do I configure my app to detect shake motion events?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, motion-detection

So let me clarify first off with showing what code i have implemented

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder 
{
    return YES;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {
        NSLog(@"FUUU");
    }
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {
        NSLog(@"FUUU");
    }
}
```

this is all in a UIViewController class

and in `- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application` i have set

```
[application setApplicationSupportsShakeToEdit:YES];
```

Yet it does nothing, not nary single motion detected. I'm not sure what else to do. This seems to have worked for many other people, so i am baffled as to why i am different...Could it be because it's through a UINavigationController? or because i load the main application via a plist and my main looks like so

```
retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

I am quite thoroughly stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses but i ended up using a different method i accessed the accelerometer in the app delegate and then send a nsnotifcation via the nsnotification center to the current ui navigation controller displayed

```
- (void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notificationName object:nil userInfo:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to detect shake gesture you need to subclass the UIView and implement the following methods (Do not implement these methods on UIViewController):

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Then add the subclassed view to UIViewController and make it first responder by calling -becomeFirstResponder on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i could not get it working ivia that method i shall post my answer forthwith

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set `[application setApplicationSupportsShakeToEdit:YES];` because this is the default value and iOS use this only for Shake to Undo/Redo.

If you want to capture the motion in your view controller you need to set this property to NO `[application setApplicationSupportsShakeToEdit:NO];` and handle it by yourself.

As described in [Event Handling Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html).

Hope this helps.

PS: Just in case, you call the wrong super in your `viewDidAppear` method. This should be :

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply and seeing my typo error, I have indeed changed it in accordance to your suggestion...But no dice, still does not work.

Comment: @Genhain do you receive callbacks motionBegan and motionEnded ? Even if you don't receive UIEventSubtypeMotionShake events.

Comment: nope it doesn't even get to the callback function which is why i am so baffled